# How to sign JSON message used by Spring Rest controller?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, signing

I have a Spring REST application that accepts JSON messages, written like

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/myhook", method = RequestMethod.POST, 
     produces = JSON, consumes = JSON)
  public @ResponseBody MyResponse doIt
     (@Valid @RequestBody(required = true) MyContractRequest request) {
      MyResponse response;
      ...
      return response;
  }
```

This works really well with almost no code to support, but now I have a requirement to sign both response and request.

I started from simply computing the shared signature of all message fields at Java level and assigning it to the dedicated signature field. However this requires to have and maintain code for computing the signatures:

```
   public void update(java.security.Signature sign) throws Exception {
    sign.update(name);
    sign.update(value);
    sign.update(etc);
  }
```

Some people around me expressed opinion that the need to write and maintain this signing code may not be the best design, and it may be better to sign the whole message as a single JSON string. I could fetch the request as a string manually, and then process JSON manually, but I really would like to preserve the Spring controller concepts.

Also, I cannot longer have the signature field in the message itself because the value of this field obviously also changes the signature of the JSON string.

Is there any way to compute the signature of the whole JSON message body on the message departure and arrival, and where to place the signature so it could be passed together with the message? One of the idea is to use the custom HTTP header for the signature. Anyway, how to compute it first?

Comment: Did you succeeded with suggested answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a servlet filter with Spring MVC and modified your content whatever you want in request and response as well

Example :

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/how-to-register-a-servlet-filter-in-spring-mvc/

or you can use Spring 3 MVC Interceptor
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/